# WPF DataGridTextColumn MaxLength

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, textblock, datagridtextcolumn

I have a DataGrid with a DataGridTextColumn, I've set TextBlock.TextWrapping to NoWrap.
If I try to display a really really long line, over 10000 characters long the display just cuts of like it's more than TextBlock.MaxWidth. The problem is that it cuts of any following newlines and effectively stops displaying anything else. How can I fix so that either the MaxWidth is longer (I've already set it to max possible) or that it at least displays the newline so that the following lines are displayed.

```
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="LogDataGrid" Margin="0,25,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" IsReadOnly="True" FontWeight="Normal" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsTabStop="True" HeadersVisibility="Column">
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Color}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="DateTime" Binding="{Binding DateTime, StringFormat=\{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss\}}" Width="Auto" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Version" Binding="{Binding Version}" Width="60"/>                       
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Binding="{Binding Text}" Width="{Binding Path=WrapText, Mode=OneWay, Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanDataGridLengthConverter}}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="{Binding Path=WrapText, Mode=OneWay, Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanTextWrappingConverter}}" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

How it looks wrapped
[image]
When it's not wrapped and the line is REALLY long
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use DataGridTemplateColumn's because you then have more control over the data such as being able to set tool tips. Make sure that the inner textblock has TextWrapping="Wrap" and the width of the template column is the size that you require. Also make sure you don't have a fixed rowheight on the datagrid.

---

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Subject" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" ToolTip="{Binding Subject}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I don't want to wrap the text.

Comment: Ok... not sure I understand the question then. When you say 'lines' are you saying that it is cutting off rows after the one which contains 10000 characters?

Comment: Yes, let say I have a text with two lines. If the lines are normal length the grid will display both lines in a single textblock in the datagrid. If the first line is long enough it will only display the first line.

Comment: I think I need more information on your datagrid and what properties you have set on it. I've built a simple example of this in a test project and have no problems.

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. The only change I've made is to remove the width binding to wrap text because I can't understand why you've done that? Setting width to auto for the column and it seems to work fine.

Comment: The binding for width is because the user can switch wrap on or off. If I wrap the text the width should be just to fill the rest of the grid. If it's not wrapping it should be as long as needed to display the text. I removed the binding for width just to test it but I still get the same result. If I copy the content of one line it will copy all the contents not just what's displayed.